LTSpice simulation running via Spicelib raises error when used an outer model
I am trying to use the Spicelib to run an LTSpice simulation in Python. This worked well when I did it with a small built-in circuit, but now currently I would like to make it work with more complex schematics, and it gave me this error:
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
     32 #Simulator and circuit definition
---> 33 circuit = AscEditor(input_loc) 
     34 LTC = SimRunner(output_folder=output_loc, simulator=LTspice)

spicelib\editor\asc_editor.py:128, in AscEditor.__init__(self, asc_file)
    126     raise FileNotFoundError(f"File {asc_file} not found")
    127 # read the file into memory
--> 128 self.reset_netlist()

spicelib\editor\asc_editor.py:245, in AscEditor.reset_netlist(self, create_blank)
    243         self.sheet = line[len("SHEET "):].strip()
    244     else:
--> 245         raise NotImplementedError("Primitive not supported for ASC file\n" 
    246                                   f'"{line}"')
    247 if component is not None:
    248     assert component.reference is not None, "Component InstName was not given"

NotImplementedError: Primitive not supported for ASC file
"LINE Normal 368 -1088 368 -1088 2

It says there is an error with the primitives and yes, there are two elements that are not found in the LTSpice's library and they are called with the .model command. I think it can't import them but I don't know why.
Do you have any solutions, how can I overcome this?
Thanks
